# How to catch click in wordpress menu item

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu, onclick

I'm trying to add and click event listener to a menu item in my Wordpress main menu through the css class name.

The menu item looks as follows:

```
<li class="custom-menu-button menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-5404">
```

Kontaktieren Sie uns

I'm using the following code:

```
(function($) {
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $(document).on('click', '.custom-menu-button', function(event){
       alert("caught");
     });
   });
})(jQuery);
```

The code works on a link with class="custom-menu-button":

```
<a class="et_pb_button et_pb_button_0 custom-menu-button et_pb_bg_layout_light" href="">In den Warenkorb</a>
```

Thank you all!

Comment: whats is the problem you are running into?

Comment: Nothing happens. meaning the function is not triggered when I click on the menu link. However it is triggered when I click the link in the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your jQuery code is targeting the `<li>` element instead of the actual link. A slight correction to target the `<a>` element might do the trick here:

```
(function($) {
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $(document).on('click', '.custom-menu-button a', function(event){
       alert("caught");
     });
   });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It did not do the trick though. I also thought I should be able to add a click event to a <li>.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The linch inside the `<li>` tag was referring to an anchor which existed. I suppose browser must have overridden the jquery function because of that.